# CSS not applied in Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring, css, spring-mvc

So I'm trying to set up a simple app using Spring MVC and I can't apply CSS to pages.

First off, here's my configuration. I'm using Java based configuration.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    res.setPrefix("/site/views/");
    res.setSuffix(".html");

    return res;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/site/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/site/");
};

public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(WebConfig.class);

    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
    dispatcherContext.register(ServiceConfig.class);

    Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}
```

My html/css/js resources are organized into folders like this:

- src/main/resources/site/views
- src/main/resources/site/css
- src/main/resources/site/js

My controller looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private CatService catServiceImpl;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/cat/{cat}")
public String cat(@PathVariable String cat, Model model) {

    final List<Dog> animals = catServiceImpl.getData(Data.valueOf(cat));
    model.addAttribute("animals ", animals );
    return "animals_list";
}
```

}

Finally, I import css into html like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/css/animals_list.css">
```

Now here's the issue:

When I load the index page I get a normal result. The css is applied and everything works fine. However, when I use a link on the index page and enter the controller which return the animals_list page I get the page which is fine, but the CSS is not applied. I get only content.
The animals_list.css is deployed (100%, checked it). 
The puzzling thing to me is why does it work on the index page but not on the animals_list page. Both are resolved by the ViewResolver and both import the stylesheet in the same manner. 
What am I missing?

Comment: your links to the stylesheets are relative; what happens if you change them to absolute links like `/site/css/index.css`?

Comment: yes, that's the problem, thanks